# -netspeed full -netdelay none

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I use Android Studio,and choose device - what ever android virtual device I choose from sdk, it will always appear like this:
`D:\android-studio\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_S_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none`
`-netspeed full -netdelay none` - this part will always appear, why?There is no problem with my code.
It is my first use of android studio, and i spend lot of time to solve many problems

Comment: I cant see the problem - you just have normal internet access from your emulator. Whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 11):

There is no problem. The parameters **-netspeed** and **-netdelay** on an Android emulator are to simulate real world network speeds & latency.

When creating an AVD you get the option to set the speed and latency of the emulator.

**Network Speed**
*Sets the initial state of the simulated network transfer rate used by the AVD. The network speed can also be adjusted in the emulator.*

**Network Latency**
*Sets the initial state of the simulated network transfer latency used by the AVD. Latency is the delay in processing data across the network. The latency speed can also be adjusted in the emulator.*

### Network Delay Emulation

The emulator lets you simulate various network latency levels, so that you can test your application in an environment more typical of the actual conditions in which it will run. You can set a latency level or range at emulator startup or you can use the console to change the latency, while the application is running in the emulator.

To set latency at emulator startup, use the -netdelay emulator option with a supported  value, as listed in the table below.

```
The format of network <delay> is one of the following (numbers are milliseconds):

Value       Description     Comments
----------- --------------- -------------------------------------------
gprs        GPRS            (min 150, max 550)
edge        EDGE/EGPRS      (min 80, max 400)
umts        UMTS/3G         (min 35, max 200)
none        No latency      (min 0, max 0)
<num>       Emulate an exact latency (milliseconds).     
<min>:<max> Emulate an specified latency range (min, max milliseconds).
```

### Network Speed Emulation

The emulator also lets you simulate various network transfer rates. You can set a transfer rate or range at emulator startup or you can use the console to change the rate, while the application is running in the emulator.

To set the network speed at emulator startup, use the -netspeed emulator option with a supported  value, as listed in the table below.

The format of network  is one of the following (numbers are kilobits/sec):

```
Value       Description   Comments
---------- -------------- --------------------------------------
gsm         GSM/CSD       (Up: 14.4, down: 14.4) 
hscsd       HSCSD         (Up: 14.4, down: 43.2) 
gprs        GPRS          (Up: 40.0, down: 80.0) 
edge        EDGE/EGPRS    (Up: 118.4, down: 236.8) 
umts        UMTS/3G       (Up: 128.0, down: 1920.0) 
hsdpa       HSDPA         (Up: 348.0, down: 14400.0) 
full        no limit      (Up: 0.0, down: 0.0) 
<num>       Set an exact rate used for both upload and download.     
<up>:<down> Set exact rates for upload and download separately.
```

*Source:*
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Answer (score 0):

On one of my machines the emulators wouldn't start from Android Studio straight after installation. (Windows 7, 8GB)

I copied the line `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd 2_7QVGAAPI_15` to the terminal, and it gave an error message (Stupidly didn't write it down)

I then ran `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe  -avd 2_7QVGAAPI_15` this worked.

Subsequently I can now run the emulator directly from Android Studio.

After setting up a new emulator I have to start them from the terminal without the the `-netdelay none -netspeed full` settings.